# Cordova project debug website as landscape instead of portrait

Tags: cordova

When I debug a new Cordova project in VS2017, it displays in portrait mode.  I am trying to make it display on the webpage in landscape mode.  I changed the `config.xml` to `landscape` instead of `portrait or landscape`, but it made no difference.  How I can debug in landscape mode?  This is my first task in Cordova so its a totally new project and my code is not interfering with anything.

Comment: if you're debugging in chrome, you can hit F12 to enter developer tools and then activate the device toolbar (button in the left of the developer tools window) and then you will see an option bar on top of you app where you will be able to whoose portrait/landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this as a webpage, but I installed Android Tools (a mobile target dropdown option), and that gave me rotate functionality.